# How to modify a variable's value via address?

Tags: lldb

I'm a newbie to LLDB. I know it's pretty easy to set a variable's value if we know it's name, e.g.:

```
p $foo = 5
```

But how can I do that if I only know it's *address*? I have read through the LLDB official page but found nothing help. Maybe I have miss something.

any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The `expression` command (which `p` is an alias for) can evaluate any C/C++ expression - so just use C syntax to do what you want.

```
(lldb) p c
(int) $0 = 10
(lldb) p &c
(int *) $1 = 0x00007fff5fbff9ac
(lldb) p *(int*)0x00007fff5fbff9ac = 5
(int) $3 = 5
(lldb) p c
(int) $4 = 5
(lldb)
```